# Maintain background scroll when modal opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had looked through many other questions on this and other sites. They were having the same issue but neither of their solutions were working for me. The most common solution that I saw was to remove the `#` from the `href` attribute of the `a` tag but my modal opens on a click of a div and other were having different cases, neither of them suited my situation.

What happens is that when I scroll down and click on a div to open up a modal, the modal opens successfully. Before that, I was having a issue that when I opened up my modal, another scrollbar was added and as per the answer of my previous question, it said to do this:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

I did it and it worked but now when I open it up, the background scrolls to top. I know that's happening because of the `position: fixed` property. I might need to specify `top` attribute for it to maintain its scroll position but everytime, the top offset would be change so their is no constant top value for `top` property.

I looked out for finding out the page's scroll offset and found that we could use `window.pageYOffset` to figure out how much the user has scrolled the background. I tried to log the value of `pageYOffset` to the console by doing this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
}
```

But everytime I scrolled it, it continuously logged `0` to the console.

I have no idea now how to fix that issue. Please help. Thanks.

[Fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SHc5P/3/)

Comment: Have you considered disabling scroll when the modal is open?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` I think its the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`body.modal-open {overflow: hidden!important;}`

to

```
body.modal-open { overflow: auto; }
```

You will then need to change the anchors from `<a href="#">` to `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` or to a proper anchor not just to the top of the page.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understood what you mean. You click on the **category** link to open the modal, correct?

If so, the problem is that you have an empty link around them `<a href="#">`, the default behavior of browsers is to scroll to top if the `href` is empty.

If you change the `href` of the link to `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">` for example, it won't scroll to top, but of course leave your website.

As Tom already said, you could alternatively change the `href`also to `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`, but it needs something else than `#`, or it will scroll to top by default.

**Or** you could add a simple jQuery script, but for that you would need to give every link of this sort a specific class, like this:

`<a class="modal_popup" href="#">`

and add this script:

```
$('.modal_popup').click(function(e) {     
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Or** you could simply write `<a href="#!">`, adding any character you like after the hash key, as long as it is no existing `ID` in your DOM.

Comment: I said, I am not using any `a` tag!